# Want to create a new instance of my class

Tags: java

I need to create a new instance of my class SimpleRGB that was created in order to change the pixels of a picture to all of one color. I know I am not creating the instance correctly, but cannot figure out how to do this right.

```
/**
 * Get the NEW image containing only the red color. The red values of this
 * new image should be exactly the same as red value of this image. The
 * green and blue values of this new image should be 0s.
 *
 * @return the NEW image (SimpleRGB) containing only the red color of this
 * image.
 */
public SimpleRGB getRedImage() {
   SimpleRGB redImage = new SimpleRGB(aRed);
   return redImage;
}
```

This is the full Class

public class SimpleRGB {

```
private int aWidth;
private int aHeight;
private int[][] aRed;
private int[][] aBlue;
private int[][] aGreen;


public SimpleRGB(int aWidth, int aHeight) {
    aRed = new int[aWidth][aHeight];
    aBlue = new int[aWidth][aHeight];
    aGreen = new int[aWidth][aHeight];
}

/**
 * Gets the width of this image.
 *
 * @return the width of this image.
 */
public int getWidth() {
    return aWidth;
}

/**
 * Gets the height of this image.
 *
 * @return the height of this image.
 */
public int getHeight() {
    return aHeight;
}

/**
 * Sets the red value at coordinate (x,y) to aRed.
 *
 * @param x the x coordinate of this image.
 * @param y the y coordinate of this image.
 * @param aRed the red value (0 - 255)
 */
public void setRed(int x, int y, int aRed) {
    this.aRed[x][y] = aRed;
}

/**
 * Sets the green value at coordinate (x,y) to aGreen.
 *
 * @param x the x coordinate of this image.
 * @param y the y coordinate of this image.
 * @param aGreen the green value (0 - 255)
 */
public void setGreen(int x, int y, int aGreen) {
    this.aGreen[x][y] = aGreen;
}

/**
 * Sets the blue value at coordinate (x,y) to aBlue.
 *
 * @param x the x coordinate of this image.
 * @param y the y coordinate of this image.
 * @param aBlue the blue value (0 - 255)
 */
public void setBlue(int x, int y, int aBlue) {
    this.aBlue[x][y] = aBlue;
}

/**
 * Gets the red value at coordinate (x,y).
 *
 * @param x the x coordinate of this image.
 * @param y the y coordinate of this image.
 * @return the value of red at coordinate (x,y).
 */
public int getRed(int x, int y) {
    return aRed[x][y];
}

/**
 * Gets the green value at coordinate (x,y).
 *
 * @param x the x coordinate of this image.
 * @param y the y coordinate of this image.
 * @return the value of green at coordinate (x,y).
 */
public int getGreen(int x, int y) {
    return aGreen[x][y];
}

/**
 * Gets the blue value at coordinate (x,y).
 *
 * @param x the x coordinate of this image.
 * @param y the y coordinate of this image.
 * @return the value of blue at coordinate (x,y).
 */
public int getBlue(int x, int y) {
    return aBlue[x][y];

}

/**
 * Get the NEW image containing only the red color. The red values of this
 * new image should be exactly the same as red value of this image. The
 * green and blue values of this new image should be 0s.
 *
 * @return the NEW image (SimpleRGB) containing only the red color of this
 * image.
 */
public SimpleRGB getRedImage() {
   SimpleRGB redImage = new SimpleRGB(aWidth,aHeight);
   return redImage;

}

/**
 * Get the NEW image containing only the green color. The green values of
 * this new image should be exactly the same as green value of this image.
 * The red and blue values of this new image should be 0s.
 *
 * @return the NEW image (SimpleRGB) containing only the green color of this
 * image.
 */
public SimpleRGB getGreenImage() {
    SimpleRGB greenImage = new SimpleRGB(aWidth,aHeight);
    return greenImage;

}

/**
 * Get the NEW image containing only the blue color. The blue values of this
 * new image should be exactly the same as blue value of this image. The red
 * and green values of this new image should be 0s.
 *
 * @return the NEW image (SimpleRGB) containing only the blue color of this
 * image.
 */
public SimpleRGB getBlueImage() {
    SimpleRGB blueImage = new SimpleRGB(aWidth,aHeight);
    return blueImage;

}

/**
 * Get the NEW image representing the greyscale of this image. The grey
 * colors are colors that the red, green and blue value are exactly the
 * same. To convert an RGB image into a greyscale image, use the following
 * formula to calculate the new value. (0.21 * red) + (0.72 * green) + (0.07
 * * blue) For example, suppose the (R,G,B) value of this image at
 * coordinate (10,20) are (10,100,200), since (0.21 * 10) + (0.72 * 100) +
 * (0.07 * 200) = 88 the (R,G,B) value of the new greyscale image at (10,20)
 * should be (88,88,88).
 *
 * @return the NEW image representing the greyscale of this image.
 */
public SimpleRGB getGreyImage() {
    SimpleRGB greyImage = new SimpleRGB(aWidth,aHeight);
    return greyImage;

}
```

}

Comment: How do you know? What is the problem? How are we supposed to guess what the problem is?

Comment: Where is `aRed` specified?  Is it a member of the class containing `getRedImage()`?

Comment: aRed is specified as a two dimensional array containing width and height, as such, aRed = new int[aWidth][aHeight];. The directions say to return the new image but I don't know how to create the new image as a member of the class SimpleRGB

Comment: post the full simplergb class

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
public SimpleRGB getRedImage() {
    SimpleRGB result = new SimpleRGB(aWidth,aHeight);
    for (int x = 0; x < aWidth; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < aHeight; y++) {
            result.setRed(x, y, this.getRed(x, y));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This creates a new SimpleRGB image with all color values set to 0 (by default all values in an int array are initialized to 0). Then it sets the red value of this new SimpleRGB to match the current RGB's red values at each point in the current RGB.

Comment: this seems to be right, but I'm getting an ArrayOutOfBounds exception at my getRed() method. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's hard to be certain without more information. But based only on your code above (assuming it's complete), the only possible issue I notice is that your constructor doesn't set the aWidth and aHeight fields, so they will get initialized to 0. This would mean the new SimpleRGB you create in this method would have all its arrays with size 0, meaning they have no indexes to access. But this should also stop the loops from running. Regardless, try adding this.aWidth = aWidth and this.aHeight = aHeight in your constructor. If that doesn't help, please post your code and the error trace.

Answer (score 1):

```
public SimpleRGB getRedImage() {
    SimpleRGB redImage = new SimpleRGB(aWidth, aHeight);
    for (int x = 0; x < aWidth; ++x) {
        System.arraycopy(aRed[x], 0, redImage.aRed[x], 0, aHeight);
    }
    return redImage;
}
```

This immediately uses private fields directly, and the low-level method System.arraycopy to do a fast copy.